# Server-client programming in python using OPC UA protocol

Tags: python-3.x

How to make OPC UA server-client program using python.
I found this link- https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/tree/master/examples
but i am unable to get flow of the codes. Please give your suggestions on it and if anybody is having any supporting documents related on same. pls share it.

Comment: Hi. I am referring to the same link you mentioned. Did you get it running.?

Answer (score 1):

What do you want precisely to be done? The structure is rather issue onces you get the swing of it. Onces it's installed run the server and check it witth he commandline

```
opcua-client
```

this gui will probably help a lot to see the structure of the server.

the opcua server exists out of a combination of nodes. some of them are standard nodes which you will see in the most basic opc server you run
When programming many of these basic nodes can be received using:

```
server.nodes#.<some node use your IDE>
```

For all custom  nodes you'll need to find them, you can do this by call get child. e.g.:

```
# To get the root node ALL other nodes are a child fro; this one eventually
root = server.get_root_node()
# To get a child:
root.get_child("0:Objects") #Objects is one of those basic nodes
# You can get a child from a path
# Once again first study the tree with the opcua-client gui
# This gui is installed automatically and under the commane opcua-client
root.get_child(["0:Objects", "0:Server"])

# The above will get the child of Objects called Server 
# directly starting at the root node
```

Now you can create child nodes yourself. You go to the node you want to add a child to usually:

```
# The Objects node
# Later you'll probably want to put that all in 1 line
objects = server.nodes.objects
id, name, type = 2, "testName", None
test = objects.add_object(id, name, type)
# This will add a object named testName to the objects node
# To acces this node again we can use it's id
server.get_node(test.nodeid)
# I know this will return test again. 
# However the ua methods "parent' parameter is this nodeid so can come in very handy
```

Creating ua methods are probably also going to be an important task of your server.

```
@uamethod
def methode(parent, input):
    print(input) # You can do all things here offcourse

server.nodes.objects.add_method(0, "myMethod", methode, ua.VariantType.ByteString, None)
```

This will add the method to the Objects node

0 is the id you wish to give it. i can't really explain what number you should choose... I usually just pick 2 ...

"mymethod" will be it's browse name that allows you to find it with the get_child and call_method methods of the nodes

method is offcourse your method

ua.VariantType. is needed to parse the data of the inputargs

None is same as above but outputargs... which my functiond didn't have

Hope this helped you a bit in understanding the most basics you can do with the freeopcua library